# get mContentInsets from a View in android

Tags: android, view, screen-size

How can I get the mAttachInfo.mContentInsets Rect from a View in Android?
I need to get the actual size of the view window.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: what you mean by *view window* ?

Comment: what do you mean by actual size?

Comment: I mean from a window-View.
Currently i'm opening a web view inside an activity and i some cases the web view is too big and been cut by the navigation bar.

Therefore I would like to get the actual windows size.